# Issue when getting reference to fragment inside ViewPager from activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I need to set a text value to `EditText` inside Fragment. There are 5 such fragments added to `ViewPager` in my activity. In order to do this I need to get reference to the fragments inside `ViewPager`. I used below `ViewPager` adapter.

```
public class MessageViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> pages;
    private HashMap<Integer,Fragment> fragmentReference;

    public MessageViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> pages) {
        super(fm);
        this.pages = pages;
        fragmentReference = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = pages.get(position);
        fragmentReference.put(position,fragment);
        return pages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        fragmentReference.remove(position);
    }

    public Fragment getFragment(int key) {
        return fragmentReference.get(key);
    }
}
```

As you can see fragmentReference HashMap uses to store all fragments inside `ViewPager`. `getFragment(int key)` method uses to get fragment from that hash map. This is how my activity looks like.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager messageViewPage;
    private Fragment message1;
    private Fragment message2;
    private Fragment message3;
    private Fragment message4;
    private Fragment message5;

    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private MessageViewPageAdapter messageViewPageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        messageViewPage = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.message_viewPage);

        message1 = new Message1();
        message2 = new Message2();
        message3 = new Message3();
        message4 = new Message4();
        message5 = new Message5();
        fragments.add(message1);
        fragments.add(message2);
        fragments.add(message3);
        fragments.add(message4);
        fragments.add(message5);

        messageViewPageAdapter = new MessageViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        messageViewPage.setAdapter(messageViewPageAdapter);
        messageViewPage.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);

        Message1 message1fragment = (Message1) messageViewPageAdapter.getFragment(0);
        Message2 message2fragment = (Message2) messageViewPageAdapter.getFragment(1);
        Message3 message3fragment = (Message3) messageViewPageAdapter.getFragment(2);
        Message4 message4fragment = (Message4) messageViewPageAdapter.getFragment(3);
        Message5 message5fragment = (Message5) messageViewPageAdapter.getFragment(4);


    }
```

But i'm getting null values for all 5 fragments `(message1fragment,message2fragment,message3fragment,message4fragment,message5fragment)`

But when I put this same code inside button on click like below, it's works fine.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Message1 message1fragment = (Message1) messageViewPageAdapter.getFragment(0);
                Message2 message2fragment = (Message2) messageViewPageAdapter.getFragment(1);
                Message3 message3fragment = (Message3) messageViewPageAdapter.getFragment(2);
                Message4 message4fragment = (Message4) messageViewPageAdapter.getFragment(3);
                Message5 message5fragment = (Message5) messageViewPageAdapter.getFragment(4);
            }
        });
```

What am i doing wrong ? I even try placing same code inside `onStart()` and `onResume()` methods, But same result. Every fragment inside this `ViewPager` has a method named `setMessage(String message)` which i intend to use to set text to `EditText` inside that fragment. I need to do that when activity start.

This is what my message fragment looks like.

```
public class Message1 extends Fragment {

    private EditText message1;

    public Message1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message1, container, false);
        message1 = (EditText) inflate.findViewById(R.id.message_1);
        return inflate;
    }

    public String getMessageOneText(){
        return String.valueOf(message1.getText());
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(){
        message1.setError("Message 1 can not be empty");
    }

    public void setMessage(String message){
        message1.setText(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onCreate the ViewPager will not have been fully initialized, with the result that getItem(...) will not have been called, so that your implementation of getFragment(...) will return null.

I'd suggest replacing getFragment with:

```
public Fragment getFragment(int key) {
    return pages.get(key);
}
```

And remove fragmentReference since it seems redundant.

Comment: By using using your changes I was able to get the fragment I want. By when I call `setMessage(String message)` inside fragment gave me null point exception that saying `message1` is null. so I place a break point on `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)' method to see whether it's get called. It didn't reached the break point before null point exception occur.

Comment: It's very likely the fragment has not been attached to the activity. You need to store the text in an instance variable of the fragment, and store it in the EditText in or after onCreateView (possibly even in onResume). Don't forget to manage the saving and restoring of this value via the savedInstanceState bundles as necessary.

Comment: I can't do that that text is dynamic getting from SQLight. :(

Comment: Then get it when the fragment is first displayed? You did seem to want it copied at creation time. If you want regular updates, then stop in a local var IF the text field is not present, otherwise set the text

Comment: Bottom line: you can't set a textedit field when it hasn't been instantiated. Either set it later, or save it locally until the textview is created.